# Como fazer uma variavel do tipo caractere receber outra em uma estrutura condicional no VisualG?

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Estou fazendo um algoritmo para mostrar a maior nota e nessa maior nota,mostrar o nome do aluno que tirou essa maior nota. A princípio parece tudo ok, mas não esta funcionando. Onde esta o erro?

```
algoritmo "melhor aluno"
var
Quantidade,cont,nota,maior : real
nome,melhor_aluno : caractere
inicio
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Escreval ("    Escola Santa Paciencia    ")
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Escreval ("Quantos alunos a turma tem?")
   Leia (quantidade)
   cont <- 1
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Enquanto (Cont < quantidade) faca
      Escreval ("Aluno ",cont)
      Escreval ("Nome do aluno: ")
      Leia (nome)
      Escreval ("Nota de ",nome)
      Leia (nota)
      Escreval ("==============================")
      Cont <- cont + 1
      Se (nota > maior) entao
         maior <- nota
         nome <- melhor_aluno
      FimSe
   FimEnquanto
   Escreval ("O melhor aluno da sala foi ",Melhor_aluno," com a nota de ",maior," pontos")
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Não esta mostrando o nome do melhor aluno,apenas a maior nota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A atribuição estava invertida:

```
algoritmo "melhor aluno"
var
Quantidade,cont,nota,maior : real
nome,melhor_aluno : caractere
inicio
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Escreval ("    Escola Santa Paciencia    ")
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Escreval ("Quantos alunos a turma tem?")
   Leia (quantidade)
   cont <- 1
   Escreval ("==============================")
   Enquanto (Cont < quantidade) faca
      Escreval ("Aluno ",cont)
      Escreval ("Nome do aluno: ")
      Leia (nome)
      Escreval ("Nota de ",nome)
      Leia (nota)
      Escreval ("==============================")
      Cont <- cont + 1
      Se (nota > maior) entao
         maior <- nota
         melhor_aluno <- nome // <================ erro aqui
      FimSe
   FimEnquanto
   Escreval ("O melhor aluno da sala foi ", Melhor_aluno," com a nota de ", maior, " pontos")
fimalgoritmo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Grades.ptg).

Comment: Deu certo.Infelizmente não posso aceitar a sua resposta ainda por conta que tem que esperar 10 minutos.Mas logo que possivel vou aceitar.
Obgd